# Connect to the same End Point using Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, client, endpoint, reconnect

I'm using the [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class in a client TCP/IP application to connect my client to a server.

I have the following code:

```
var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
                        ProtocolType.Tcp);

client.Connect(endPoint);

try
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Do work...
        // Receive/Send data from/to server
    }
}
catch (SocketException)
{
    /* At some point the server disconnects...
    Exception catched because the server close the connection
    Socket error 10054 - WSAECONNRESET */

    // So I try to reconnect
    if(client.Connected == false)
    {
        /* The following line throws a InvalidOperationException.
        Message: After disconnecting the socket, you can reconnect only 
        asynchronously from a different EndPoint. BeginConnect must be 
        called on a thread that will not close until the operation completes.*/
        client.Connect(endPoint);   

        /* So I try instead Socket.BeginConnect, but the following line
        throws a SocketException 10061 - WSAECONNREFUSED */
        client.BeginConnect(endPoint, ConnectCallback, client);

        /* And also the following code throws a 
            SocketException 10061 - WSAECONNREFUSED */
        client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
                                ProtocolType.Tcp);
        client.Connect(endPoint);
    }
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a list of socket error.

So, at some point the server close the connection, I need to know what is the best method to know when the server is ready for accept another connection and how to connect again to the same End Point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSAECONNREFUSED means, the server is not accepting your connection request.

You will have to retry to connect in a loop with sleeping a few seconds between the retries. There is no way for the client to know when the server is available again, without trying to connect.

Comment: I was thinking to the same solution, but [I would prefer not to use Thread.Sleeep](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx).

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but you definitly should not call `client.Connect()` in a tight loop. When doing your connect in a background thread there is nothing to be said against using `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: But have I to create a new socket?

Comment: @Nick take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698999/how-to-reuse-socket-in-net. I think disposing the old and creating a new socket is the easier way.