# Can't connect to same local TCP server twice

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to connect to a TCP server with .NET's `TcpClient`. For testing, the server is on my own machine. It worked initially, but not when I restarted my application.

So I wrote this small bit of code to try connect/disconnect twice and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
const int clientPort = 29501;
const int port = 29500;

using (var client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, clientPort)))
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);

using (var client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, clientPort)))
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
```

When I run this code, i get a `SocketException`:

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the using blocks properly release the socket?

Comment: Your local connections cannot share the same **local** port.

Comment: @Amy But `using` should disconnect the last connection from that port before the new one starts, right?

Comment: `Dispose()` just tells the GC that the object is available for collection.  It does not immediately force garbage collection, hence it doesn't immediately cause the connection to be closed.

Comment: Have a look at [`LingerState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.lingerstate(v=vs.110).aspx), it's possible your connection may be remaining open after `Close` is called. I'll also just point out that you don't *have* to specify an endpoint for the client to bind to - you can leave it out and [one will be generated for you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc1d0e0f(v=vs.110).aspx), so unless you actually need to bind both clients to the same port, it's safer to let the system allocate you a free port.

Comment: @Amy Garbage collection shouldn't matter here. Dispose exists precisely so you can clean something up immediately, without waiting for garbage collector and finalizer to kick in.

Comment: @hnefatl Tried it just now. `LingerState = new LingerOption(false, 0)` doesn't help.

Comment: **Why** are you doing this? Why do you want to connect from a specific client port? The port will be in wait state after use anyway, see duplicate. You can't do this, other than to configure the TIME_WAIT interval to a very low value ([which you don't want to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757289/tcp-option-so-linger-zero-when-its-required)), or by asking the OS's TCP/IP stack to do its job and assign you a free client port.

Comment: @relatively_random You would need to set `Enabled` to `true`, not `false`.

Comment: @hnefatl My mistake. Still doesn't work, though.

Comment: @relatively_random No, it won't work for the reason described in the duplicate. With a bit of poking you could have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698999/how-to-reuse-socket-in-net) from the dupe, which provides some more things you could try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f(v=vs.110).aspx) using constructor with parameter of type `IPEndPoint` also binds to that specified port. In your case you don't need clients to bind to another ports, only server socket must be bound to a TCP port.

So you can use parameterless constructor instead:

```
const int port = 29500;

using (var client = new TcpClient())
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);

using (var client = new TcpClient())
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
```