# How to reconnect to a socket after disconnecting c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working on a chat room that has 2 buttons. Connect and Disconnect. I want the user to be able to disconnect then reconnect again after inputting a different IP and port, but once they disconnect they are unable to reconnect.

This is how I bind the sockets

```
            //binding socket
            epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textLocalIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textLocalPort.Text));
            sck.Bind(epLocal);
            //Connecting to remote IP
            epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textRemoteIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textRemotePort.Text));
            sck.Connect(epRemote);
            //Listening the specific port
            buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

            if (sck.Connected) { connection.Text = "Connected"; }
            else { connection.Text = "Not Connected"; }
            connection.Visible = true;
```

And this is how I disconnect

```
            //Disconnect from the chat
            sck.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            if (sck.Connected) { connection.Text = "Connected"; }
            else { connection.Text = "Not Connected"; }
```

But when someone tries to reconnect, an error shows up saying "**An invalid argument was supplied**"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reuse socket in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698999/how-to-reuse-socket-in-net)

Comment: Where would I input the `sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)` because If I call it at the beginning the program wont open but if I call it when I press the "Conncet" button nothing happens

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that you need to reuse the existing socket. You need to create a new socket when you want to connect to another IP address and port.

Comment: Oh alright thank you